# What is "Your response is uncalled for"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I had a heated email conversation with one of the vendors,  I gave him nicely when he unnecessarily mentioned something. He responded likewise. *Your response was uncalled for.*

Can you please explain me what it means?

Comment: ***Uncalled-for***: 
*If a criticism, insult, remark, or action is uncalled-for, it is unfair, rude, or unkind and therefore considered to be unnecessary:
an uncalled-for remarK* - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/uncalled-for

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Interpretation requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It means that the speaker felt your "response" was an insult.  As such, the sentence is a veiled insult.